# MySQL Stored Procedure - if then not functioning

Tags: mysql

I'm converting SQL Server stored procedures to MySQL and running into issues. I have a stored procedure with an IF THEN ELSE that, while not giving errors, is not returning any data either and I'm not seeing the problem to fix it. The queries by themselves are correct and return data but don't seem to work in the stored procedure. This is a simplified version of the real query just FYI.

The SQL for creating the stored procedure is:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_GetVolunteerAwardsList`;
    DELIMITER //

    CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_GetVolunteerList`( IN glAward_in int)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE glAward_In INT;
        DECLARE awardType_In varchar(100);
        DECLARE awardActive INT;

        IF (glAward_In) = 0 THEN 
            SELECT * FROM tbl_volunteer
        ELSEIF (glAward_In) = 1 THEN
            SELECT * FROM tbl_volunteerpositions
        END IF;
    END
//
```

As always, any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: First of all, do you have the same problem running the sp with the "simplified" query?

Comment: Does `glAward_In` this variable has some values...try printing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the glAward_In parameter or variable.
The SP is receiving the parameter glAward_in, i in lower case.
Then there is a DECLARE that declares a different variable glAward_In, i in upper case.

The if is done using the glAward_In in uppercase which is not set in any place of the SP. And the parameter in lower case is not used anywhere in the SP.

I think you have to remove the DECLARATION of the variable in upper case, and use the parameter in lowercase for the IF evaluation.

Comment: THANK YOU - I believe the real sproc was okay with the case sensitivity, but just to be safe, I changed everything.  However, it was the declare that was killing it.  Once I removed that, everything worked.  I've not been successful In previous attempts at an if-then-else statements in sprocs but didn't have time to sort it out.  This will help me a lot in the future and gives me something that I know works, to build on.  Many, Many thanks.